# I am getting warnings in my android program after I updated my project to android x library in android studio

Tags: android, warnings, android-strictmode

Below are the warnings I am getting.

> 1) Android compatibility - Google play store has marked API '
>   Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols()'
>   grey listed and they cant guarantee that this API will work on
>   existing version of android.
>
> 2) Android compatibility - Google play store has marked API '
>   Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V' grey listed and they cant
>   guarantee that this API will work on existing version of android.

I haven't enabled strict mode in my project. How to resolve these warnings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in android Q google restricted usage of hidden API through reflection that is why you are getting these warnings.

Comment: So how to solve this? @MohdFaizan

Comment: there may be some external lib that you are using in project like okhttp because I dont think you are directly using hidden api in your project.

Comment: So first check which one is using that API if you found any library is using than you dont have any option to remove that library or if you are you using directly in your code than you need to find alternate

Answer (score 1):

In android P, google began restricting usage of none sdk interfaces.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

You can checkout sdk alterntives for the interface you using